# android: how to retrieve the file content from app folder of drive in android app

Tags: android

I am uploading a file into drive in app folder. Now i uninstall the app then again install, and trying to retrieve the app folder content, but i am not getting any file content and logcat shows that GoogleApiDrive connection failed, but then again pressing button to retrieve content, i am getting the data. Please, any one help me how to solve retrieving the data first time after uninstalling the app, but letter i am able to retrieve the data ?

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        super.onConnected(connectionHint);

        //query for file name in drive
        query = new Query.Builder()
        .addFilter(Filters.eq(SearchableField.MIME_TYPE, "text/plain"))
        .addFilter(
                Filters.eq(SearchableField.TITLE, "appfolderdata"))
                .build();
        Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(
                metadataCallback);

    }

    final private ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult> metadataCallback = new ResultCallback<MetadataBufferResult>() {

        DriveId driveId;
        @Override
        public void onResult(MetadataBufferResult result) {
            if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
                finish();
            }
            //get metadata if backup file is present in drive
            MetadataBuffer metadata = result.getMetadataBuffer();
            System.out.println();
            if (metadata.getCount() > 0) {
                System.out.println("metadata.getCount() is : " + metadata.getCount());
                driveId = metadata.get(0).getDriveId();
                System.out.println("meta data drive id is : " + driveId);
            }
            metadata.close();
            if(driveId != null){
                Drive.DriveApi.fetchDriveId(getGoogleApiClient(), driveId.getResourceId())
                .setResultCallback(idCallback);
            }else{
                if(count < 3){
                    Drive.DriveApi.query(getGoogleApiClient(), query).setResultCallback(
                            metadataCallback);
                    count++;
                }else{
                    showMessage("Problem while retrieving results");
                    if(dialog != null){
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```